# Show that $\sup_{\|g\|\leq \delta_n}\left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n g(Z_i)\right|\rightarrow_{\text{a.s.}}0.$ when $\delta_n\rightarrow 0$?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, limits-and-convergence

UPDATE: The result below can be understood as an almost sure stochastic equicontinuity condition. I don't know of any result establishing primitives of almost sure stochastic equicontinuity. If you know, this would very likely help me answer the question.

I need the following almost sure convergence result:

Let $\|\cdot\|$ denote a norm on a functional space (could be $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ or $\|\cdot \|_2$ in $L^2$, for example).  $\mathcal{G}=\{g:\mathcal{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$ of measurable functions. Let $Z_1,Z_2,\dots$ be $i.i.d$ random variables with $E[g(Z_i)]=0$ for any $g\in \mathcal{G}$. Let $\{\delta_n\}$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $\delta_n\rightarrow 0$.
Then, under **ADDITIONAL ASSUMPTIONS**,
\begin{equation*}
\sup_{g\in\mathcal{G} \text{ s.t. }\|g\|\leq \delta_n}\left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n g(Z_i)\right|\rightarrow_{\text{a.s.}}0.
\end{equation*}

Note that all random variables are defined in the same probability space and are independent draws of the same distribution. The number $n$ here denotes the size of the sample, and the almost sure convergence is over the distribution of the $Z_i$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. The space $\mathcal{G}$ does not depend on $n$, and $g$ is not random.

I need to find which reasonable assumptions could be made to establish this result. $\mathcal{G}$ is $P$-Donsker? Lipschitz functions? Bounds on moments? etc.

---

**Attending requests for clarification of the background:** this result is needed to establish a stochastic equicontinuity condition on a linear regression estimator with a generated regressor (it means that one of the regressors is estimated). This is a high level result, in the sense that it is a result for a generic estimator for the regressor, we want to give conditions that this estimator must satisfy, but not specify the estimator. I am using results in a paper by Chen, Linton and Keilegom (2003) which establish the consistency of the bootstrap for estimators which are based on the optimization of a function of the data, the parameter of interest and a nuisance infinite dimension parameter. So, suppose the model is $E[Y|X,W]=\beta X+\gamma h_0(W)$, but $h_0$ is not known.  The term is thus estimated and the regression is done on $\hat{h}(W)$ instead. If it helps, you can think of $h_0(W)=E[V|V\leq 0, W]$, for another variable $V$ which is observed in the data, for example. (FIY: this is a huge simplification of the true situation, so don't give me suggestions about how to estimate the model I just described. In the actual model $V$ is not observed and must be predicted out of sample with machine learning and optimization methods.)

In order to apply one of the results in the paper I mentioned, I need to prove that some quantities such as the one above are $o_{\text{a.s.}}(1)$. For example, I give you a simplified version of one of them:
\begin{equation*}
\sup_{h,h_0\in\mathcal{H} \text{ s.t. }\|h-h_0\|\leq \delta_n}\left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n \left[X_i(h(W_i)-h_0(W_i))-E[X_i(h(W_i)-h_0(W_i))\right]\right|
\end{equation*}
I need to show that several objects that look more or less like the one above are $o_{\text{a.s.}}(1)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for any sequence of positive $\delta_n\rightarrow 0$. Note that I can make assumptions about  $\mathcal{H}$, $X$ and $W$. For example, I can say that $\mathcal{H}$ is the space of measurable negative Lipschitz functions, and I can say that $E[|X|^4]$ and $E[|W|^4]$ are finite. Basically I need conditions that would allow me to establish this result.

At the essence this is an empirical process. Define $\mathbb{G}_nf=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n f(Z_i)-E[f(Z_i)]$ and let $\mathbb{G}$ be the Brownian Bridge, then if $\mathcal{G}$ is $P$-Donsker, $\mathbb{G}_ng\rightsquigarrow\mathbb{G}g$ for every fixed $g$. This is a convergence in distribution in a functional space. I need to show that $\sup_{\|g\|_{\mathcal{G}}\leq \delta_n} |\mathbb{G}_n g|\rightarrow_{\text{a.s.}} 0$.

I hope this is clearer and someone can help me. I ran out of ideas of things to try and need a fresh take.

Comment: I think you should wait a little bit more than 9 hours on Math Stack Overflow.

Comment: To me this seems to some sort of "Rundumschlag" (german). Can you make your question more concrete, specifying the function space (what is the $\sup$-norm) and clarify your problem. For example is your $\sup$ measurable as a supremum over uncountable many functions?

Comment: As stated the claim does not hold, as $Z_i$ could be uniform on $[-1,1]$ and for each $n$, the function  $g$ could be an odd function from $[-1,1]$ to $[-\delta_n,\delta_n]$, chosen to satisfy $g(Z_i)=\delta_n$ for all $i \le n$.  More care is needed in the supremum.

Comment: @DieterKadelka Define any normed space, suppose that the norm exists. I even took out the $\sup$ from the description (I simply meant $||g||=\sup_{z\in\mathcal{Z}}|g(z)|$ and you can suppose that the functions $g$ are defined in $\mathcal{Z}$ with image in $\mathbb{R}$ and are bounded.) I think it is clear in the question that I have plenty of freedom to decide the functional space. If you know of a theorem that may achieve this, I can probably assume its requirements. I added explanations to the question. See new paragraph.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Yes, it should be obvious that as stated it does not hold, as I mentioned that even to prove this convergence in probability one needs bounded second moments. Your example forgets the requirement in the statement that $E[g(Z_i)]=0$.  Please see updated comments.

Comment: Note that in my example g is an odd function so the requirement does hold.

Comment: @YuvalPeres The expectation is taken over the distribution of $Z_i$. The function $g$ cannot vary in $n$.

Comment: @DieterKadelka Sorry, googled "Rundumschlag" and cannot figure out what you mean. If you want more information: I am writing a theorem to prove the consistency of a bootstrap procedure. I can make assumptions in that theorem, I decide which ones they are within reason. However, to prove said theorem I need to use an existing result whose requirements make it necessary for me to establish the result above.

Comment: @Caetano: I don't know the correct translation, its something like "sweeping statement" or "sweeping attack". Further, your comment that $g$ cannot vary in $n$ looks strange, since you work with the supremum over all $g$ such that $\|g\| \leq \delta_n$. In your answer to my comment the norm seems to be $\|g\| = \|g\|_\infty$. Please make your question more concrete, otherwise the discussion may be endless.

Comment: @DieterKadelka Thanks for explaining. Indeed the norm can be $||g||_{\infty}$. That is what I have in mind, but I could use a different norm, if someone knows of a result which uses a different norm. I don't understand the confusion with the function $g$, but I will try to clarify. Say $g\in\mathcal{G}$ a fixed space which does not vary with $n$. The function is not random, in any way. The only randomness comes from the $Z$. I will update the statement.

Comment: @Caetano, while you're editing, perhaps you could include in the post that your goal is proving the consistency of a bootstrapping procedure, and explain what $\delta_n$, $g$ and $Z_i$ are in that context. Then some of your conditions might make more sense than they do now.

Comment: @MattF. Thanks! I need to step out for a minute now, but as soon as I return I will add that as well.

Comment: @MattF. Done! Hope this is clear now.

Comment: @Caetano, I think it's clear enough, but there are probably other ways to present the question that would be more likely to encourage good responses.

Comment: @MattF. Glad to adapt. Any suggestion? I'm a bit lost as to what is needed. My background is Statistics and this notation is so standard there that I have a hard time figuring out what is the issue with clarity here.

Comment: The function $g$ must depend on $n$ because of the assumption on its norm. I understand you do not want it to depend on the values of $Z_i$ but the notation you use is not consistent with that wish. Please try to reformulate.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Perhaps you can explain what you mean? It is really not clear to me. The sup is taken over all the functions in the space $\mathcal{G}$ with image between $-\delta_n$ and $\delta_n$. This means that the group of functions over which the sup is taken changes with $n$. However, a specific function $g$ is fixed. For example, think that one of the functions could be $g(Z)=E[V|Z]-E[V]$, where the expectation is taken over the joint distribution of $V$ and $Z$.

Comment: @Caetano If you write out in detail the definitions of the a.s. convergence and supremum, you will see the problem. Assume the norm is $L^\infty$  norm, that   the $Z_i$ are uniform on $[−1,1]$ . Then for each $n$  the sup is taken over such a large class of  functions $g$, that it includes  odd functions from $[−1,1]$ to $[-\delta_n,\delta_n]$ chosen to satisfy $g(Z_i)=\delta_n $ for all $i \le n$.

Comment: @Caetano I think it will help clear up the  misunderstanding if you write exactly what statement you have proved for convergence in probability; as far as I can tell,  the supremum you wrote does not converge to zero even in probability in the example mentioned in my last comment, assuming $\delta_n=1/(1+\log n)$ for instance. If, however, the supremum is outside the probability that the normalized sum is large,  then all is well, but that is not what convergence in probability of the supremum means.

Comment: @YuvalPeres I think I understand what you mean, thanks! You are saying that for all events, among odd functions from $[-1,1]$ to $[-\delta_n,\delta_n]$ there is always one such that $g(Z_i)=\delta_n$ for that event. Yes, this makes sense, and there may be a problem with the result in probability as well then. I will be thinking about this. On the background I have been working on just relaxing that assumption from the theorem I wanted to use anyway, because I think this requirement need only hold in probability and for sequences $\delta_n=\delta/n^{1/4}$.

Comment: @Caetano: From the discussion its not clear to me, what you want to show: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{g∈G ~s.t. ~\|g\|≤\delta_n} \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n g(Z_i) \right| = 0$ (here Yuval Peres has a counterexample) or something like $\sup_{g∈G} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n g(Z_i) \right| = 0$, which seems to be true (I have not checked it). In the second formula the introduction of $\delta_n$ does not make sense.

Comment: @DieterKadelka The first is exactly what I want to show, but remember that the question is about what types of conditions would have to be imposed for this to hold. I am sure this would not hold in general. Yuval's counter example is very helpful though. I think it would be ruled out with a requirement that $\mathcal{G}$ has only increasing functions. Also, I am reading up on stochastic equicontinuity and I'm finding several instances where Lipschitz style conditions show up.

Comment: @DieterKadelka Also, just FIY, I did not make up the $\delta_n$ in the sup, it is literally the requirement of the theorem I want to use. I am also finding several similar requirements to that whenever stochastic equicontinuity conditions show up, and it is always the sup over the space of the parameters in a shrinking neighborhood of the right value. Requirements are usually that the expectation of the sup goes to zero, or some convergence in probability though, I only saw a.s. convergence in this instance.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Ok, I have found a general result for this convergence in probability in Pakes and Pollard Lemma 2.17 (http://www.stat.yale.edu/~pollard/Papers/PakesPollard89Econometrica.pdf) In fact, it's a more general result. $g$ here is their parameter $\theta$. It's in probability though, not almost surely. I will be studying it though, see if I can figure this out.

Comment: @Caetano  Lemma 2.17 in Pakes and Pollard is not as general as the statement you were making- that statement does not hold for convergence in probability, as the example I indicated earlier shows. The supremum needs to be over a more restricted class.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Again, my question has never been whether that statement holds in general. I know it does not hold in general. The question is whether there are any known sufficiently respectable conditions under which it may hold. Lemma 2.17 in Pakes and Pollard does give such conditions for the convergence in probability: Euclidean class with envelope function with a bounded second moment.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Overall I am finding that I am having a communication problem here. I think that mathematicians think: "under such and such conditions, does this conclusion hold?" While applied math people think: "which reasonable conditions are sufficient for this conclusion to hold?"

Answer (score 0):

A sufficient condition to establish the result above for the convergence **in probability** is if $\mathcal{G}$ has finite entropy with an envelope function $M$ which satisfies $E[M(Z)^2]<\infty$. This allows us to apply Theorem 1 in https://cowles.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/pub/d10/d1059.pdf ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20151218135126/https://cowles.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/pub/d10/d1059.pdf), DOI: [10.1016/S1573-4412(05)80006-6](https://doi.org/10.1016/S1573-4412(05)80006-6)).

Unfortunately I could not find any result for **almost sure** stochastic equicontinuity, which is probably the answer to this problem. I will look it up further. If you know anything about this, please let me know.