# Almost sure stochastic equicontinuity

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, limits-and-convergence

Suppose $\mathcal{G}$ is a normed closed class of functions with finite entropy and envelope with a finite second moment (details below), and $g_0$ is a function in the interior of that class. Let $Z_i$, $i=1,\dots,n$ be $i.i.d$ random variables sampled from the distribution $P$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and suppose that $E[g(Z_i)]=0$ for all $g\in \mathcal{G}$. Finally, let $(\delta_n)$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $\delta_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Then, does
\begin{equation*}
\sup_{||g-g_0||\leq \delta_n}\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n g(Z_i)-g_0(Z_i) \right|\rightarrow_{a.s.} 0?
\end{equation*}

Some details:

1. By finite entropy, I mean that $\int_0^\infty \sqrt{\log N(\varepsilon,\mathcal{G},||\cdot||)}d\varepsilon<\infty$, where $N$ is the covering number for balls of size $\varepsilon$.
2. Let the envelope function be $M$, the the second moment is $\int M(z)^2P(dz)<\infty$.
3. The norm $||\cdot||$ may be either $\sup_z|g(z)|$ or $\left(\int |g(z)|^pP(dz)\right)^{1/p}$ for any $p\in \mathbb{N}$.
4. If convenient, you may assume $\delta_n$ to be a decreasing sequence, and/or $\delta_n=o(n^{1/2-\alpha})$ for some $\alpha>0$.
5. Note that the result above holds for convergence in probability. (Lemma 2.17 in Pakes and Pollard (1989) [http://www.stat.yale.edu/~pollard/Papers/PakesPollard89Econometrica.pdf](http://www.stat.yale.edu/%7Epollard/Papers/PakesPollard89Econometrica.pdf) or Theorem 1 in Andrews (1993) https://cowles.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/pub/d10/d1059.pdf ).

Can anybody help? I have attempted a lot of things, but nothing is working. I have also tried to ask a similar but apparently confusing question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364845/show-that-sup-g-leq-delta-n-left-frac1-sqrtn-sum-i-1n-gz-i) and in [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744951/help-me-prove-that-sup-g-leq-delta-n-s-ng-sqrtn-rightarrow-a-s). Even if you know some result which may be related, it will help. Even if the result has stronger conditions than the ones stated here, it will help. Thanks.

Comment: I think the answer depends on how fast $\delta_n$ goes to $0$. The answer should be yes if $\delta_n$ goes to $0$ fast enough, and no otherwise. To determine an exact threshold, I think one needs a full-blown paper. However, I think one would have problems publishing such a paper, as the a.s. convergence does not seem natural here.

Comment: @losif Pinelis. Indeed, it may come to a speed of convergence issue. For convergence in probability the speed is irrelevant, as the result exists for any series $\delta_n=o(1)$. It could also come down to restrictions in the function space. You are right that the almost sure convergence does not seem natural and primitives for almost sure stochastic equicontinuity are not showing up anywhere in my lit searches. Unfortunately this condition is sometimes required in papers about the convergence of bootstrap procedures, which is what I need this for. I'm losing hope.

Comment: @losif Pinelis: I should mention that establishing the result for a rate any faster than the one in my point 4 would not help me though.